# Using react-table to populate a table based on a user. When I change the user on the page it renders infinitely and react errors out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table-v7

So I have a user drop down menu that allows a person to impersonate a user to get a list of buckets.  If you pick a different user it then makes an api call to then get a new list of buckets based upon that user. I am using react-table to create a table with information about the user's buckets.  I can change the user on the other pages and the user gets updated and nothing explodes. But if I do it on the bucket page, it returns this:[image]

The API call which happens in the parent component of my bucketTable component in the useEffect hook and that is tied to the user that I drop down from the app.js.  The API call fires off and returns a list of buckets which I then pass down to my bucketTable component which then takes it and inserts it into a react-table.

[image: app.js]

I have an onChange event that bubbles up to App.js from my navbar and then drop the selected user down to the buckets page. Which then does an API call using useEffect which is then tied to the user field that I am passing around.

[image: bucket.js]

[image: bucket.js]

bucketTable.js
[image: bucketTable]

so the issue is that when I change the userDropdown on the navbar which then updates that value in the buckets.js component to get the list of buckets, this table page gets overwhelmed.  I don't understand why I see my use effect is firing only when user is fired.  I have done console.log statements and see that it only gets fired when I change it once, but this happens.  This makes me think that something is rerendering over and over again causing this issue.  Please help been pulling my hair out on this and I can provide more details upon request.

EDIT:
So when I change the user ON the bucket page which renders the bucketTable component I see that the bucket Table component is being rerendered a billions times...still looking into this will update when I have more information.

[image]

this is my bucketTable.js which is being rendered a TON when I change the user.

```
import "../index.css";
import { useTable } from "react-table";

const BucketTable = ({ buckets }) => {
    console.log('BucketTable Rendered')
    const data = []
  const columns = [
    {
      Header: "Bucket Name",
      accessor: "bucket",
    },
    {
      Header: "Created By",
      accessor: "created_by",
    },
    {
      Header: "Storage Label",
      accessor: "storage_label",
    },
    {
      Header: "Zone",
      accessor: "zone",
    }
  ];

  // Must only get the array cleansing of objs
  buckets.buckets.forEach((x) => data.push(x));
  console.log(data)

  const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
    useTable({
      columns,
      data
    });

  return (
    <>
      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.value}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map((row) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.value}</td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
};

export default BucketTable;
```

buckets.js which calls the bucketTable.js component

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import BucketList from "../Components/BucketList";
import useCollapse from "react-collapsed";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import * as AiIcons from "react-icons/ai";
import BucketTable from "../Components/BucketTable";

// TODO: Shift from cards to table
const Buckets = ({ user }) => {
  const [bucketList, getBuckets] = useState(null);
  const { getCollapseProps, getToggleProps, isExpanded } = useCollapse();
  const [selectedACL, setValue] = useState("private");

  const callGetBuckets = () => {
    console.log("callGetBuckets Called")
    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      user: user,
    };
    notify("loading");
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/rest/v1/buckets", { headers })
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('fired off?')
        getBuckets(data);
        notify("dismiss");
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect fired")
    callGetBuckets();
  }, [user]);

  const notify = (type) => {
    switch (type) {
      case "success":
        toast.success("Bucket Created", {
          toastId: "Success",
        });
        break;
      case "fail":
        toast.error("Bucket Creation Failed", {
          toastId: "fail",
        });
        break;
      case "loading":
        toast.loading("Loading...", {
          toastId: "loading",
        });
        break;
      case "dismiss":
        toast.dismiss();
        break;
      default:
    }
  };

  const handleSubmission = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", user: user },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        bucket: e.target.Name.value,
        storage_label: e.target.StorageLabel.value,
        acl: selectedACL,
      }),
    };

    fetch("http://localhost:5000/rest/v1/bucket/create", requestOptions).then(
      (res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
          notify("success");
          console.log('fired off as well')
          callGetBuckets();
        } else notify("fail");
      }
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ToastContainer theme="theme" />
      <div className="content">
        <h2 className="bucketHeader">Buckets</h2>
        <div>
          <p>Returns a list of buckets that a user has access to view.</p>
        </div>
        <div className="collapsible">
          <div className="header" {...getToggleProps()}>
            Create Bucket
            <span>
              {isExpanded ? (
                <AiIcons.AiOutlineArrowUp />
              ) : (
                <AiIcons.AiOutlineArrowDown />
              )}
            </span>
          </div>
          <div {...getCollapseProps()}>
            <div className="content-collapsible">
              <form className="createBucketForm" onSubmit={handleSubmission}>
                <label className="collapsible-label">
                  Name:
                  <input type="text" name="Name" />
                </label>
                <label className="collapsible-label">
                  Storage Label:
                  <input type="text" name="StorageLabel" />
                </label>
                <div className="dropDownForm">
                  <label className="collapsible-label">
                    ACL:
                    <span className="dropdown">
                      <label className="dropLabel">
                        <select
                          value={selectedACL}
                          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
                        >
                          <option value="private">private</option>
                          <option value="public-read">public-read</option>
                          <option value="public-read-write">
                            public-read-write
                          </option>
                          <option value="authenticated-read">
                            authenticated-read
                          </option>
                        </select>
                      </label>
                    </span>
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div>
                  <input className="formSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {bucketList && <BucketTable buckets={bucketList} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Buckets;
```

Comment: First of all add code as text instead of images. Is this the only place where the user is changed? This `forEach` looks suspicious.

Comment: Yes the drop down is changed on any page.  But if I go to the about page, and change the user, and go to buckets it works.  BUT if I am on the buckets page and change the user it explodes. 

That forEach because I was having trouble getting the array from the API without sending ONLY an array and not the array from the API response.

Updating with actual code vs pics.

Comment: Why do you use this `data` variable instead of `buckets.buckets`?

Comment: 1) it wont let me use buckets.buckets which is the array inside the obj.
which is this = ``` {
    "buckets": [
        {
            "bucket": "UITestdos",
            "created_by": "user1",
            "storage_label": "mahou2",
            "zone": "zone1"
        }
    ]
}
```

and when I set it equal to a single variable as data it does work, but the render issue still is there without that foreach.

Also I think react-table look specifically for the word data, because when I did it as test it errored out as data being undefined.  it has to be the word data.

Comment: But `data` is also an array. Try `useTable({
      columns,
      data: buckets.buckets
    });`

Comment: I believe that your render issue can be interested to the table. I looked through the code and can't find the reason. Do you have a public repository on GitHub?

Comment: the data: buckets.buckets works as passing that in to get rid of the gross forEach, but the infinite render is still happening.

No I don't have a public git.


I am in the same boat of thinking it is the react-table is doing something rendering causing the component to be re-rendered over and over again.

Comment: Try disabling different parts of the code until the issue stops appearing.

Comment: I have stopped the error by commenting out all the HTML in bucketTable.js and the  

const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
    useTable({
      columns,
      data: buckets.buckets
    });
 definitely something with react-table causing this infinite rendering.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this was to move the const columns out of the component file.  I moved it into its own file and imported it to the parent component then dropped it down as a prop and everything worked fine from there.  THe reasoning I am still baffled as to why that happened.  I still had issues when I imported it directly to the table component but when I brought the columns in as a prop it fixed itself.  But that was the fix for the infinite rendering.

`const columns = [ { Header: "Bucket Name", accessor: "bucket", }, { Header: "Created By", accessor: "created_by", }, { Header: "Storage Label", accessor: "storage_label", }, { Header: "Zone", accessor: "zone", } ];`